# How can I connect my controller to a view in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I think I have a problem understanding how the data loaded by *controller* should be binded and become available to the *view*. For the purpose of this question I have crafted [a small example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/BMbfk/14/) that uses ember-rest to load data.

As you can see in the jsFiddle, what I want to achieve in this example is to bind my `testData` to `BlockView` which is rendered using the `blocki` template. What is an appropriate way to do this in Ember?

To get an idea of what the fiddle would look like when it is running properly replace the binding to `blocksController` to directly bind to the `testData`. I have done this in [another version of the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/BMbfk/16/).

```
{{view App.BlockView blockiBinding="App.testData" }}
```

Of course the blocks render properly in this version -- but that is not how I want to do this. I want to learn how to properly (as recommended by Ember) connect the `blockController` to the view and get the data from it. In a real scenario the data will be obtained from a REST API and that is why I am using ember-rest in this example.

If you fix [that jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/BMbfk/14/) with your ninja moves, please take a few seconds and explain the concept behind how it works. I found it very difficult to obtain up to date information about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You connect a view with a controller by using
a) The appropriate naming scheme
b) connect the outlets

For example if you have a view BlockView you should have a controller BlockController. Then from the view you can access the content of the controller directly.

```
App.BlockView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'block'
});

App.BlockController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  block: { name: 'block 1', children: [ {name: 'child1' }, {name: 'child2'}] }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="block" >
   <div>Block Name: {{block.name}}</div>
   {{#each child in block.children}}
     <div>Child Name: {{child.name}}</div>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

What I also miss in your code example is the router. This one takes care of the appropriate 'glueing' of all the components. Take a look at the router in Trek's tutorial (which is btw up to date and represents the way how an application should be written).

In the router you will define the connectOutlets method in which you load the view that should be rendered into the outlet. And if you stick with the naming scheme from above, you have direct access from your view to the controller

**Update**

I got your code running with some modifications:

- You don't need to initiate the controllers on your own. App.initialize() will take care of that for you
- I modified the resource controller to object controller and removed the resource block but of course this makes no different to ObjectController. Just for basic understanding working with plain ember.js objects makes your life easier.
- It's in JavaScript not Coffee Script - sorry for that :D

Unfortunately I am not able to create a jsFiddle (don't ask why - no clue :)). So I have added the data to a GIST - https://gist.github.com/3832764.

**Update 2**

And I also managed to create now a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qV5wu/2/ :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to fix the issues you mentioned in the fiddle. I have also added a router and connectOutlet for `blocks`. Could you please take a look and see if you can identify what I am still missing: http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/BMbfk/22/

Comment: Thanks rit, I appreciate the effort you have put in providing a complete answer. However, there is an error in the jsFiddle and it does not work: `Unable to find template "application"`. Did you forger to hit *update* on jsFiddle? If you just run it will not save. Oh also you have to *fork* the jsFiddle first I think so that you can save your edits. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I guess it is an issue with the browser. I tested the jsFiddle and it works with Safari and Chrome but it doesn't with Firefox. But when I run the stuff from my local hard drive (see the GIST) then it does also work in Firefox.

Comment: Although your example shows how to use the router, it still does not show how to connect directly to the controller. You are still loading static data directly into the view. As I mentioned in the question, I want to receive the data from the controller.

Comment: My team mate was able to simulate asynchronous loading of data through controller building on you example, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/focuser/bw4jy/2/ thanks for your answer, it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through http://trek.github.com/ and see if that helps you any. From what I'm seeing of the fiddle the example you have is very similar to the one provided in the tutorial.

In particular the area I'd look at is connectOutlet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have read that but I dont think I have fully understood what `connectOutlet` is for. I thought it was optional. I think that tutorial is a bit old though, you can see the jsFiddle that was made for it no longer works: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ZKXyg/